# PHP Hit Counter with DATE

Tags: php, file, web

I'm using the following code for an hit counter:

```
$fp = fopen("counterlog.txt", "r"); 
$count = fread($fp, 1024); 
fclose($fp); 
$count = $count + 1; 
$fp = fopen("counterlog.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($fp, $count); 
fclose($fp);
```

In the file I only have a number, but I would like to obtain a file in the following way:

```
18/09/2015  10
19/09/2015  11
```

So I want the count grouped by day and date separated by a tab.

I know I can use database for doing that, but in this specific case I want to use only text file.

Is possible to obtain that?

Comment: If you don't want to use a database (which you really should), then at least add file locking ([`flock`](http://php.net/flock)). While you could store dates+counts line-wise, it would also be simpler to just use JSON or serialize() for file storage then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should meet your requirements.

```
<?php


$dateexists = false;

if(!file_exists('counterlog.txt'))
{
    $fh = fopen('counterlog.txt', 'w');
    fclose($fh);
}

$datecounts = file('counterlog.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($datecounts as $key => $datecount){

    list($date, $count) = explode("\t", $datecount);

    $count = (int) $count;
    if($date == date('d/m/Y'))
    {
        $datecounts[$key] = $date."\t".++$count;
        $dateexists = true;
    }
}
if(!$dateexists)
{
    $datecounts[] = date('d/m/Y')."\t1";
}

$fh = fopen('counterlog.txt', 'w');
if (flock($fh, LOCK_EX)) {
    foreach($datecounts as $datecount)
    {
        fwrite($fh, $datecount.PHP_EOL);
    }
    flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
}
else
{
    //couldn't lock, might want to do stuff here
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: How to add file lock?

Comment: @helloimyourmind I've updated my answer with file locking.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't update the count, is always 1.

Comment: I found a problem: when the day change, "date + 1" is stored near the past day, and not in a new row. What's the problem?

Comment: @helloimyourmind It should work now. It was a problem with where line breaks were being added.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to not use a file for this. If two requests are coming it at almost the same time, you can corrupt your file. Of course you can solve this problem with a lock, but a database solves the problem better.

I would say to use a csv format for this. This is at least a formal format, which allows you to more easily read and write to it.

```
$fp = fopen( "counter.txt", "r" );
while( !flock( $fp, LOCK_EX ) ) {
}

$csv = Array();
$currentdate = date( "d/m/Y" );
$rowavailable = FALSE;

while( ($row = fgetcsv( $fp, 100, " " )) !== FALSE ) {
  if( $row[0] == $currentdate ) {
    $row[1] = $row[1] + 1;
    $rowavailable = TRUE;
  }
  $csv[] = $row;
}
fclose( $fp );

if( !$rowavailable ) {
  $newrow = Array( $currentdate, 1 );
  $csv[] = $newrow;
}

$fp = fopen( "counter.txt", "w" );
for( $csv as $row ) {
  fputcsv( $fp, $row, " " );
}
fclose( $fp );

flock( $fp, LOCK_UN );
```

Comment: In regards to your opening remarks, wouldn't the script requests be handled sequentially by the server in a queue? I agree that a database would be the optimum solution here.

Comment: @MartynShutt Luckily not. If stackoverflow would be running on php, you say that most of us would never see anything. Look up threads, and for example the "threadlimit" of a http deamon as Apache.

Comment: Ah, multiple threads. Thanks. I'll delve into the topic a little further.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
<?php

$today = date('d/m/Y');
$dd=null;
$fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if ($fp) {
    while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
        $dd[] = explode(' ', $line);
    }
} else {

} 
fclose($fp);
$fw = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
if(is_array($dd) && count($dd) > 0){

foreach ($dd as $key => $value) {
    $cc = $value[1];
    if($today == $value[0])
    {
        $cc++;
    }
    fwrite($fw,$value[0].' '.$cc);
}

}else
{
    fwrite($fw,$today.' 0');
}
fclose($fw);

exit;
?>
```

what iam doing is ,reading the file data line by line and making an array and then writing it again , same day count will be grouped

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Sumurai8´s answer using CSV right away, one can also reduce the code a bit further. A regex to read the file into an assoc array is pretty trivial:

```
$file = file_get_contents("cnt.txt", LOCK_EX);
preg_match_all("/^  ([\d/-]+)  \s+  (\d+)  /mix", $file, $dc);
$date_counts = array_combine($dc[1], $dc[2]);
```

Having a `["2015-11-11" => 22, ...]` array then simplifies updating the per-date counter to just:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");  // proper ISO format
$date_counts[$date] += 1;   // extra notice for first hit
```

Writing it back with [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) becomes rather easy as well, and simplifies locking a bit:

```
array_walk(
    $date_counts,
    function(&$cnt, $date) {
        $cnt = "$date $cnt";
    }
);
$file = implode("\n", $date_counts);
// add another fopen/flock/LOCK_SH here
file_put_contents("cnt.txt", $file, LOCK_EX);
```

Note that this still isn't an atomic write. (But *not* using a database is *your* decision and problem, not mine.)

Answer (score -1):

fwrite($fp, date('d/m/Y') . ' ' . $count);

Comment: But I have to verify if the last row date is the same date